# LOAD DATA INFILE into Single Field on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, perl, load-data-infile

I am very much a noob at MySQL.. I need to populate one field with a .txt file.

My script currently reads:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/attachments/file.txt' into table files (data);
```

However, when I run the query, MySQL shows that I have updated not just *one* record, but multiple records -- each line of my .txt file going to a different field.

Is it possible to require my script to upload the entire .txt file into a single field?

Thanks!

Comment: So, does each row of your text file contain a single value, that you want to put into a single column in a table, one row in the text file = one row in the table? Can you give an example of the text file?

Comment: The text file is on the large side: around 200 lines of text. Is it even possible to load all of this data into a single field and still maintain the structure of the file?

Comment: @bill: "upload the entire .txt file into a single field". Explain to me how load_file() DOESN'T do that, then feel free to criticize.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of dong this, depending on the details of your scenario:

### LOAD DATA INFILE

You probably want something like this:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/data_file.csv'
    IGNORE
    INTO TABLE `databasename`.`tablename`
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY '\n'
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (column1)
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

This will import from `/path/to/file/data_file.csv` into `databasename.tablename`, with each complete line in the text file being imported into a new row in the table, with all the data from that line being put into the column called `column1`. More details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

### LOAD_FILE

Or you could use the LOAD_FILE function, like this:

```sql
UPDATE table
  SET column1=LOAD_FILE('/path/to/file/data_file.csv')
  WHERE id=1;
```

This will import the contents of the file `/path/to/file/data_file.csv` and store it in `column1` of the row where `id=1`. More details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file). This is mostly intended for loading binary files into `BLOB` fields, but you can use it to suck a whole text file into a  single column in a single row too, if that's what you want.

### Using a TEXT Column

For loading large text files, you should use a column of type TEXT - it's can store very large amounts of text with no problems - see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) for more details.